# Menu - onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) is not showing anything

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to put a menu bar but it never shows anything in the app - i thought that it could be the language that i was using (that was Kotlin), but even in Java it doesn't make any difference
I tried to use "return true" and using setHasOptionsMenu(true) as well but nothing happens.
The version that I'm using is android-studio-2022.2.1.20-windows (Flamingo). I even changed the android studio version and watched every single video on yt about the menu and how to put it, even though i followed all the steps, it still doesn't show me anything. I just wanted to put a menu bar for a search icon and a logout part.

Here is the xml for my menu, res>menu>home_menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="About"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

Now the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if your app's theme has ActionBar.

Comment: If you share the theme.xml or styles.xml code, I can help.

Comment: It's "NoActionBar":
 Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar, im not being able to change it to have an ActionBar

Comment: I answered. Can you check?

Comment: It worked, this account is new so i havent been able to vote yet but Sr thank u sm!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Theme.Material3.DayNight` as the base theme.